# P2P messanger in java

Tags: java

I have to write P2P messanger in java.
Could you give me any suggestions how can I start? What should I use to create this application? If you know some tutorials about this topic, Ill appreciate them very much!
Greetings!

Comment: Some programming school assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use only Core Java here are my picks:

Your program must have a server thread. It must listen to incoming requests on a specific port. Every time a request comes, it must spawn a new thread. The new thread must create a GUI for communication. Bear in mind that the server must pass on the Socket instance to the newly spawned thread for further communication.

Using the socket instance you can communicate with the remote client.

Use Swing for the GUI.

The GUI must allow users to connect to any IP address. When the user connects to any IP address it must do so on the port where your server thread is listening.

I am assuming that you are familiar with the basics of multi-threading, network programming and swing.

Comment: Thanks, but why do I need a server in a P2P application?

Comment: You do not actually need a "server" per se. But what you need is a thread that listens to incoming requests. Otherwise how are you going to communicate with other clients.